# createElement just in Main Document not in iFrames inside the Document

Tags: javascript, safari

If i create an element with...

```
var elm = document.createElement("p");  
document.body.insertBefore( elm, document.body.firstChild );
```

i got this p-element inside every body element - cooool!
but also in every iframe body inside the main document.

**How can i define the creation just in the maindocument?**
something like?

```
document.body.firstChild.ownerDocument
```

*(the script should do the job from a injected.js via safari extensions)*

Comment: i will move away from stackoverflow.. i feel blamed by the "admins"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i got this p-element inside every body element - cooool!

You should only get it in the one, single body that the document has.

> but also in every iframe body inside the main document.

Those are separate documents, and that code shouldn't touch them unless you include that code in your embedded documents.

If you *are* including that code in those documents, then you could test to see if you are (not) in a frame:

```
if (top === window) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert into the firstChid of the body :

```
var elm = document.createElement("p");  
var body = document.body;
body.insertBefore(elm, body.firstChild);
```

EDITED: http://jsfiddle.net/vgbsf/1/

Comment: No, aside from storing `document.body`, you code is identical to that of the original question.

Comment: but.. this solution is still producing "clones" in iframes in safari extension. in fiddle shows its like working.. i find out that safari.extensions load injections of code in every document instance. even in iframes. so for the extension DOM it looks like every iframe is just something like the main document.. so the first solution with     if (top==window) {} does the job very well;

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you could use jQuery:

`$('body').prepend("<p>im new here...</p>")`

check it - http://jsfiddle.net/HLQ8W/

Comment: thats right.. :) but i wanted a none-jquery solution. was a driven by the idea not to lower performance from safari while pageloading.. because as extension it would be loaded in every page, just to do this job..  i was really thinking about the same idea as first..

Comment: and by the way, native javascript is compatible as possible. :-P